# Error: No Resource Identifier found for attribute "click_remove_id" in package 'com.jams.music.player'

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am a beginner and trying to follow a tutorial and learn through it. However I am getting the above error: No Resource Identifier found for attribute "click_remove_id" in package 'com.jams.music.player'. It's inside the layout folder.Please help me out on this one. Here is the code giving the error..

> ```
> <!-- Current queue drawer -->
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/main_activity_queue_drawer"
>     android:layout_width="320dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="end" >
>
>     <TextView
>       android:id="@+id/empty_queue_text"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>       android:text="@string/queue_is_empty"
>       android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>       android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
>       android:visibility="invisible"
>       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/divider" >
>
>         <com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
>             xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jams.music.player"
>             android:id="@+id/queue_list_view"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
>             dslv:click_remove_id="@+id/remove_song_from_queue"
>             dslv:drag_enabled="true"
>             dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/playlists_flipped_handle"
>             dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
>             dslv:drag_start_mode="onDown"
>             dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
>             dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.8"
>             dslv:remove_enabled="true"
>             dslv:remove_mode="clickRemove"
>             dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.5" />
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
            xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jams.music.player"
            android:id="@+id/queue_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            dslv:click_remove_id="@+id/remove_song_from_queue"
            dslv:drag_enabled="true"
            dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/playlists_flipped_handle"
            dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
            dslv:drag_start_mode="onDown"
            dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
            dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.8"
            dslv:remove_enabled="true"
            dslv:remove_mode="clickRemove"
            dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.5" />
```

remove this name space from mentioned widget and add it to the parent layout.`xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jams.music.player`

below mentioned things you should have to mentioned in `attrs.xml` as resource

```
           click_remove_id
           drag_enabled
           drag_handle_id
           drag_scroll_start
           drag_start_mode
           float_alpha
           max_drag_scroll_speed
           remove_enabled
           remove_mode
           slide_shuffle_speed
```

Answer (score 0):

Boopathi's answer is right.

It just need the datatypes for those attributes. Add the below mentioned code in attrs.xml file

```
    <attr name="click_remove_id" format="string" />
    <attr name="drag_enabled" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="drag_handle_id" format="integer" />
    <attr name="drag_scroll_start" format="float" />
    <attr name="drag_start_mode" format="string" />
    <attr name="float_alpha" format="float" />
    <attr name="max_drag_scroll_speed" format="float" />
    <attr name="remove_enabled" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="remove_mode" format="string" />
    <attr name="slide_shuffle_speed" format="float" />
```